# Promised a higher position

Tags: promotion

I was promised orally numerous times that I would receive the Senior Vice President position at my company by my immediate supervisor. The CEO passed away unexpectedly and my immediate supervisor moved up to CEO. Now this person is back-pedaling when I bring up the promise that I would move up to SVP. I've worked my behind off and taken on so many extra responsibilities (successfully) over the last twelve years, preparing for this. The new CEO also reports to the Board of Directors. What can I do?

Comment: This was getting close votes as off-topic. Since legal issues are usually off-topic here, I've removed the part asking about legal recourse. To get a better idea about out this site works, please see the [tour](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: @GreenMatt "What can I do?" is still too generic probably. Something like "How do I argue my case to the new CEO based on X?" is more suitable.

Comment: @Lilienthal: I get your point, but was trying to avoid being heavy handed.

Comment: @GreenMatt No worries. It's a good edit, but it's up to Linda to clarify the question when it needs a more significant edit.

Answer (score 5):

The first question is whether or not there is even an open SVP spot.  There might not be.  It's quite likely your supervisor made promises (s)he simply couldn't keep once (s)he took over and found out more details about what is going on in the company.  Who knows what the former CEO had promised to various people and you can bet they are now trying to call in those favors.

Your best bet would be to keep going to lunch with the CEO and make sure you have plenty of visibility solving big problems.  Be seen as someone who is helpful during the transition rather than being a problem to be dealt with.

A few other things that might be blocking you boil down to exactly how much (if any) of the company stock the CEO actually controls.  If it's very little in comparison to the board then they might have their hands completely tied in regards to the top spots.

Some boards are relatively inactive and leave the CEO to do their job, only checking in every so often to give advice.  Others take a far more active role and dictate to the CEO how to run things - including who the top people are.  Often the top spots are based on verifiable credentials that "look good" far more than having anything to do with capability and if there are openings they might be seeking people that would look good for a possible buyout.  Given this person was promoted into that job when it was vacated unexpectedly I'd bet it's the latter.

If the transition was very recent then you can bet the CEO has his/her hands full with figuring out what's going on in the company, soothing any ruffled feathers on the board and generally making sure a lot of people don't just bail out.  If the previous CEO was THE driving force of the company then the new one has to convince 3 very different groups (board, employees, customers) that they are capable of handling the job.  Any major changes at this point, like large internal promotions, need to be seriously considered in that light before acting on them.

Honestly, the fact you tagged this "legal" without knowing that promises by people without power are worthless says to me that perhaps you aren't ready for the role.  Of course, I don't know you and I certainly don't know the exact situation you are in.  My answer is simply based on what I've seen elsewhere and my perspective from running a company.

Answer (score 2):

You should apply for the job and see what happens. If you have prepared well and done the work, you stand a good chance. Keep your relationship friendly as possible because the CEO will have a large say in the matter when the time comes. They usually are not the ONLY people with a say in the matter, so he/she may be regretting making a promise they can't keep straight away, but still mean to try their best for you.

Unfortunately verbal promises are often only worth the paper they're written on.

Legal recourse's are off topic here, but I doubt you have any anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A verbal agreement is worth the paper it's written on.

Unless you want to take it to the B.O.D. you're out of luck.

Apply for it, and be ready to move on if you don't get it.

Comment: B.O.D. ?   not sure what that means.  Could you expand on it?

Comment: @NotMe: Board Of Directors.

Comment: I feel dumb - just haven't seen it referenced that way.  Usually it's just shortened to board... :)